# Accessing JSON value results in undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{

"headers":[
        {"title": "Action", "width": 3, "class": "centeralign"},
        {"title": "ID", "width": 4, "class": "leftAlign"},
        ..
        ..
    ],
"rows": [
            {"cells": [
                {"data": "Edit", "width": 3, "class": "centeralign"},
                {"data": "030194"},
                ..
                ..
           ]}
        ]
}
```

For every "data" in JSON, I'm dynamically generating a table cell. This is what I have:

```
$.each(response.rows, function(index, rows){

    $("tr#columnData").append("<td>" + rows.cells.data + "</td>");
});
```

rows.cells.data is resulting in "undefined".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cells` is an array in your JSON structure, so you need to loop through it:

```
$.each(response.rows, function(index, row) {
    $.each(row.cells, function() {
        $('tr#columnData').append('<td>' + this.data + '</td>');
    });
});
```

Comment: I'll send you large sums of money if you'll change the `rows` parameter to `row`. *(This offer expires in 3 seconds, and in no way constitutes a legally binding contract.)* ;o)